# Top tag dot is flying a little higher than normal

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, profile-page

I'm not sure if this is linked to all the changes that seem to be going on with the profile page at the moment and I do hate pointing out such trivial matters but here goes.

The dot next to the top tag is flying a little higher than normal:

[image]

Shouldn't this be sitting more central with the tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for reporting this. You are correct: the badge should be centered. This has been fixed and will be corrected in the next production build.

It will now look like this:

[image]